# Corollary to the density theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following statement

> "If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $x < y$, then there exists an irrational number $z$ such that $x < z < y$.

So, I have begun by applying the density theorem  that there exists a rational number $r$ such that $x < r < y$. The theorem also states that $r$ cannot be equal to $0$ but I am not sure why. Does it have something to do with the Archimedean Property?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac{x+y}2$ is an irrational number then we can set $z=\frac{x+y}2$.
If not, then let $n$ be a natural number that is large enough so that $(y-x)n>1$ (by the Archimedean property). Then set $z=\frac{x+y}2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{100}\frac{1}n$. This is an irrational number because we assumed that $\frac{x+y}2$ is rational and $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. I leave the verification that $x<z<y$ up to you.

Comment: but I still don't get why this means that r cannot be equal to 0.

Comment: @Michelle: What they may mean is that one *can* choose $r$ not to be $0$. Of course if $x$ is negative and $y$ positive, then $r=0$ will work fine, but maybe you want to have an $r\not=0$ and the theorem gives you that.

Comment: Okay. Do you mind explaining why we can choose r ≠ 0. Maybe I'm really just not getting it

Comment: You can use literally the same argument as in my answer.. if $\frac{x+y}2$ is not zero, then set $r=\frac{x+y}2$. If $\frac{x+y}2=0$, then ..

Comment: then I'm assuming you set r not equal to 0

Comment: Yes, for example just set $r=(y-x)/100$ (which isn't $0$, because we can assume $y>0$).